# How to convert this complex number to exponential form?

Tags: complex

I have $Z = {\frac{2+i}{2-i}}$. I need to write it in exponential form, i.e. $Z = r*e^{i{\phi}}$.

I simplified the given example to ${\frac{3 + 4i}{5}}$, i.e. $a={\frac{3}{5}}, b={\frac{4}{5}}$. Therefore, $r = 1$.

Then I calculate $cos({\phi}) = a / r = 3 / 5, sin({\phi})=b/r = 4/5$. How do I calculate ${\phi}$ from here?

The online [Complex Number Exponential Form](https://www.dcode.fr/complex-number-exponential-form) given ${\phi}=tan^{-1}({\frac{4}{3}})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{Abs, Arg}@((2 + I)/(2 - I)) // Through
#1 Exp[I #2] & @@ %
```

> {1, ArcTan[4/3]}
>
> E^(I ArcTan[4/3])

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as i said i get the right answer by using some tool, but i wanna understand how to calculate myself

Comment: If you're just interested in the math itself, and not how to do it in _Mathematica_, may I suggest asking it on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: yes, actually...